# GLM (Poisson regression) and Linearity

Tags: regression, time-series, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, poisson-regression

I understand that an assumption of Poisson regression is a linear relationship between the transformed expected response in terms of the link function and the explanatory variables. Therefore you would only include variables with a linear relationship in the model.

If I wanted to look at the relationship between different hours that total counts occur, could I not include the variable 'Hour' in the model as it would not have a linear relationship. Thank you

Comment: The premise given in the last sentence in the first paragraph is false. Just as in ordinary regression you might accommodate nonlinear relationships between $\eta$ and the predictors $\eta=X\beta$ by expanding the set of predictors in various ways (i.e. doing more than just directly appending each $x_i$ column to make an $X$-matrix). Naturally some specific nonlinear relationships are linearizable in such fashion but a wide array of possible relationships are, including cyclical (periodic) functions with known cycle length.

Comment: Unfortunately, my last sentence got slightly mangled; I had edited it for clarity but didn't complete the edit by the look. It should say "Naturally not all nonlinear relationships...". I had also intended to  go on to mention generalized additive models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Poisson regression, the assumption is about the relationship between the log of the expected counts and the explanatory variables, which should be linear. However, this doesn't mean you cannot include variables like 'Hour' that might not have a straightforward linear relationship with the outcome.

You can handle non-linear relationships by:

- Transforming the variable (e.g., using a quadratic term like `Hour^2`).
- Splines or Polynomials: Using spline functions or polynomial terms to capture the curvature.
- Treating `Hour` as a categorical variable, which does not assume any specific form of relationship. Rather than use this as your final model (you will have 24 coefficient estimates if events are happening all day), you could use it to inform the transformation or degree of polynomial or spline knots.

Comment: We were writing answers simultaneously Some of our ideas overlap, but some of yours are good ones that I didn't think of.  +1.

Comment: @PeterFlom sorry that I beat you to it ! Hopefully the OP can take away some good info from both our answers :)

Comment: @Randomname you are very welcome :)

Comment: A good answer, though a more likely transformation for hour would be something like `cos(hour * 2 * pi / 24)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm reading this to mean that you think the event might happen more often at certain times of day.

You can include a spline of hour, or you can transform it another way that suits your hypothesis.  E.g. if you think the event is least likely in the middle of the night, you could change hour to "distance from midnight" so that e.g. 11 PM and 1 AM would both get 1. Or some trig function of hour might work.  It depends on what you suspect is going on.

Comment: Concerning trig functions, you can try to use `sin(2*pi*hour/24)` together with `cos(2*pi*hour/24`)  as predictors (`2*pi*hour/24` is the "hour angle").